# Batch request to odata v4 from angularjs getting error

Tags: odata, asp.net-web-api2, batch-processing

I am trying to call a batch request from angularjs using a service(angular-http-batch.js) to an ODataV4 Web Api endpoint.But i am getting the error

"The 'Content-Type' header value 'application/http; msgtype=request' is invalid. When this is the start of the change set, the value must be 'multipart/mixed'; otherwise it must be 'application/http'."

Is i missed out any configuration in odata ?.